# HANA SQL:Import Excel Field formatted as date into Dataset or convert excel date values (eg. 43830 for 31.12.2019) to Date

Tags: excel, date-format, hana

I'd like to upload from an Excel file with a column formatted as date in excel to a dataset in the Analytical workspace of Tagetik on HANA  database.
As excel stores date values as numbers (eg43830 foe 31.12.2019) I get an orror uploading in a dataset field with type date as 43830 is not a valid date format.
Uploading the excel field in a Dataset field with type text or number works, but then I have the numeric representation there.

So I'd like to convert this number (43830) to a valid date (31.12.2019) -  I did not find an appropirate function in HANA SQL.

Thanks for some ideas.

best

Sabom

Answer (score 1):

Why do you dont convert the number to a date as string in excel before upload and just use that date? Sounds like the easiest. Nontheless, you could use ADD_DAYS in HANA. The number you are seeing are days since January, 1st 1900. So ADD_DAYS with a base of 1900-01-01 should work.

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your tipp - good idea! I searched already for the DATEADD function (MS SQL) but HANA is different :( 
I cannot change the excel as it is from external source and must be uploaded as provided.
best Sabom